# iPhone/iPad how-to

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

As a followup to my earlier question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006851/universal-app-how-to), I have some more questions:

1. When developing a universal app, do I have make the UI (buttons etc) look bigger on the iPad screen or I can use the same size I used when developing for iPhone/iPod touch screens?. When adding icons to buttons (Glyphish Pro, etc), do I have to have bigger icon sizes when targeting for iPad?. I wanted to support iPad2 (non retina and retina) thru mini.
2. Do I have to surround every bit of code with try...catch block to catch exceptions when creating a universal app?
3. I wanted to have a Settings screen when a user presses Settings button. Do I always have to use Settings.bundle or create my own settings UI shown here: http://pttrns.com/categories/18-settings?. I'm using NSUserDefaults class in my app. I don't want my settings information to show in the global settings section on the iPhone/iPad.
4. What if I wanted to change my domain name after completing my app and before publishing it to the App store?. I'm seeing that the domain name I have given is disabled in XCode and I can't edit it.
5. Lastly, I wanted to add animations when showing several view controllers when the user clicks on buttons. My app is a Single View application with several more view controllers. Is animation supported when loading view controllers on the iPad?

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ofc you need bigger for ipad retina to look great
   2 no
   3 usually I am using my own
   4 you have to edit a file manually, and delete a propery , after that you can edit
   5 yes

Comment: Thank you. I have couple of png files for several of the UIButtons. The png file sizes are 18x25 (non-retina) and 36x50 (retina). Are these good for iPhone 3GS thru iPhone5 and also iPad2 thru mini?. I read another post that says I have to have png filenames as ~iphone.png and ~ipad.png. I'm totally confused here. Please explain

Comment: that is true, also for retina "myimage@2x" and none retina "myimage" try it! it works with smulator too!